# Java - Why the subclass of ArithmeticException class is not called?

Tags: java, exception, arithmeticexception

I want to modify the `ArithmeticException` output message. So, for that i did few experiments. I extended the `ArithmeticException` class by`ExtenderClass` class. The point of this question is not only to find the solutions to modify the `ArithmeticException` exception message but also to tell why some of cases below are working as expected but some are not? Following are the cases along with their outputs:

**Case 1:**

```
// Both the classes are in the same file 'MyClass.java'
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int a,b,c;
        a = 1;
        b = 0;

        try{
            c = a / b;
        }catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
        }

    }
}

class ExtenderClass extends ArithmeticException{
    // ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
I caught: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

**Result: Works fine as expected.**

---

**Case 2:**

```
// Both the classes are in the same file 'MyClass.java'
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int a,b,c;
        a = 1;
        b = 0;

        try{
            c = a / b;
        }catch(ExtenderClass e){
            System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
        }

    }
}

class ExtenderClass extends ArithmeticException{
    // ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:9)
```

**Result: Means that the `throw/catch` is not fired. Why the `ExtenderClass` is not fired? In fact its extending the `ArithmeticException` class?**

---

**Case 3:**

```
// Both the classes are in the same file 'MyClass.java'
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int a,b,c;
        a = 1;
        b = 0;

        try{
            c = a / b;
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
        }

    }
}

class ExtenderClass extends ArithmeticException{
    // ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
I caught: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

**Result: Works fine as expected.**

---

**Case 4:**

```
// Both the classes are in the same file 'MyClass.java'
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int a,b,c;
        a = 1;
        b = 0;

        try{
            c = a / b;
            throw new ExtenderClass();
        }catch(ExtenderClass e){
            System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
        }

    }
}

class ExtenderClass extends ArithmeticException{
    // ...
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:9)
```

**Result: Means that the `throw/catch` is not fired. Why the `ExtenderClass` is not fired? In fact its extending the `ArithmeticException` class?**

---

Why the `ExtenderClass` class that extends the `ArithmeticException` is not fired? But when i use the `ArithmeticException` directly, it gets fired.

Comment: because the `ArithmeticException` class is fired internally by the compiler and on the same time it gets fired if it is in the next `catch` case, may be that is the case. I am not an expert in java but sharing knowledge as much as you have is not bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have declared a custom exception as a subclass of `ArithmeticException`, there is no way that you can get `a / b` to throw your custom exception.  The JLS specifies that (integer) division by zero will throw `ArithmeticException`; see [JLS 15.17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) paragraph 3.

Since the exception that is being thrown is `ArithmeticException`, you won't be able to catch it as your custom exception.

```
try {
   c = a / b;      
} catch (ExtenderClass ex) {
   ...
}
```

will catch `ExtenderClass` and subclasses of `ExtenderClass`.  `ArithmeticException` is *not* a subclass of `ExtenderClass`, so the above *won't* catch it.

---

Your reason for creating `ExtenderClass` is ...

> I want to modify the `ArithmeticException` output message.

You would be better off writing some special-case code to substitute a different message for the  "/ zero" message when you print it out.

Or ....

```
try {
   c = a / b;      
} catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
   thrown new ExtenderClass("Division by zero is cool!, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a sub-class of `ArithmeticException` doesn't cause an instance of that sub-class to be thrown when you divide an `int` by 0.

Dividing an `int` by 0 will always throw the base `ArithmeticException` class.

Your `ExtenderClass` will only be thrown if you throw it explicitly in your code:

```
    try {
        c = a / b;
    } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new ExtenderClass ();
    }
```

In the only case you explicitly throw `ExtenderClass` (case 4), that throw statement is never reached, since the previous statement causes `ArithmeticException` to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments:

```
try{
    c = a / b; // ArithmeticException was thrown at this line
    throw new ExtenderClass(); // So this line was not executed 
}catch(ExtenderClass e){  // This line will catch ExtenderClass and it's sub class. However, ArithmeticException is super class of ExtenderClass, not it's sub class, so it won't be caught
    System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing your cases:

1) You cause and catch an `ArithmeticException` as expected. `ExtenderClass` is un-used.

2) An `ArithmeticException` is thrown and is not caught by *your* code as `ExtenderClass` is *more specific* than `ArithmeticException`.

3) You cause and catch an `ArithmeticException` as expected. Note: execution does not reach the point where you explicitly throw an `ArithmeticException`.

4) You cause an `ArithmeticException` with the line `c = a / b` and it is not caught by *your* code as `ExtenderClass` is *more specific* than `ArithmeticException`. Execution does not reach the point where you explicitly throw an `ExtenderClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice observation.

Please find my explanations:

**NOTE:**

- As per you code snippet **`ArithmeticException`** is a **SuperClass** and **`ExtenderClass`** is **SubClass**
- In Java **`catch`** block will execute only if the exception defined inside it is same as the exception thrown in **`try`** block or broader than **`try`** block.

**EXPLANATIONS:**

- ***Case 1***
  Here you are throwing `ArithmeticException` and catching it by the same class, so catch block is executing as expected.
- ***Case 2***
  Here you are throwing `ArithmeticException` at line no. 9 `c = a / b;`
  and trying to catch by its subclass which is not possible.
  So the exception is not been handled in catch block.
  You should catch by same or **Broader** Exception(Super class).
- ***Case 3***
  This case is similar to case 2 except you are catching by **Same Exception**(ArithmeticException) and throwing `ArithmeticException`  2 times

  `try{
      c = a / b;
      throw new ArithmeticException();
  }catch(ArithmeticException e){
      System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
  }`

  This line `throw new ArithmeticException();` will not execute as exception thrown in previous line.
  Here at line  `c = a / b;` you thrown `ArithmeticException` and catching the same in `catch` block so it works as expected
- ***Case 4***
  In this case you are throwing `ArithmeticException` first then `ExtenderClass` so only 1st exception will be thrown and control will never goes to second as per the below code.

  ```
  try{
      c = a / b;
      throw new ExtenderClass();
  }catch(ExtenderClass e){
      System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
  }
  ```

  Here you are trying to catch by Subclass(`ExtenderClass`) which is not possible. so `catch` block will not handle the exception.